# ServiceNow "Greater than or is", "Less than or is", and "Between" String compare operators

Tags: servicenow

In a condition-type field, or in like a filter for a list, if I select a field that is a string-type field, there are three compare operators in the list of available operators that I do not understand the function of when it comes to strings.  I was hoping someone could help me understand these three compare operators:

1. Less than or is
2. Greater than or is
3. Between
4. Also, what does "Matches Pattern" refer to?  I at least understand the other three in other contexts, but what does "Matches Pattern" refer to, something about Regex, which I am familiar with?

Here is a screenshot so that you can see exactly what I am talking about, just to make sure I am being clear with what I am asking.  Thank you in advance.

[String operator screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DBii4.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### String operators

With string less than and greater than take into consideration alphabetical order. Letter "A" is bigger than "B" and so on. If you provide more letter you will limit results even more.

Having records:

```
Albania
Andorra
Armenia
Austria
Azerbaijan
Belarus
Belgium
Bosnia & Herzegovina
Bulgaria
```

When you filer `greater than or is "Belg"` you will receive the following result:

```
Belgium
Bosnia & Herzegovina
Bulgaria
```

When you filer, `greater than or is "Belg" AND less than or is "Bo"`. You will see:

```
Belgium
Bosnia & Herzegovina
```

You will get the same results using between operator.

---

### Matches Pattern

Matches Pattern is pretty well described in documentation. Please have a look here for details [doc link](https://docs.servicenow.com/bundle/kingston-platform-administration/page/administer/field-administration/concept/c_PatternMatching.html)

In short "pattern" is like regex but only have asterisk (*****) and question mark (**?**). Asterisk means any number (including zero) of any character where question mark means exactly one.

> - **the story** matches **the story** but not **that story**.
> - ***story** matches **the story** and **that story**, but not **that story is the best**.
> - **st?ry** matches **story** and **stxry**, but not **my story** or **stairy**.
> - ***b?gus*** matches **bogus, my bogus story**, and **His bagus machine**, but not **my bgus story** or **my baigus story**.

Comment: Thank you, nailed it on the head